# How the array of std::shared_ptr in C++ works

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I am a c++ beginner and learning about smart pointers and inheritance. I have a base class `Shape`(abstract) and as derived classes I have Triangle, Isosceles and Equilateral.

My idea is to print appropriate print message for each class according to the type which is pointed the base class, which I have declared in the main() as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual const void triangle()const = 0;
    virtual ~Shape(){ std::cout<<"Shape Deleted\n";  }
};

class Triangle: public Shape
{
public:
    virtual const void triangle()const override
    { std::cout<<"I am a triangle\n";   }
    virtual ~Triangle(){ std::cout<<"Triangle Deleted\n";   }
};

class Isosceles : public Triangle
{
public:
    virtual const void triangle()const override
    {   std::cout<<"I am an isosceles triangle\n";  }
    virtual ~Isosceles(){ std::cout<<"Isosceles Deleted\n";   }
};
class Equilateral: public Isosceles
{
public:
    virtual const void triangle()const override
    {   std::cout<<"I am an equilateral triangle\n";  }
    virtual ~Equilateral(){ std::cout<<"Equilateral Deleted\n";   }
};
```

When I use traditional way of creating a pointer object using `new` key word, the distructors of all classes works perfectly(out put is given below).
The `main()` was:

```
int main()
{
    Shape *Obj[3];
    Obj[0] = new Equilateral();
    Obj[1] = new Isosceles();
    Obj[2] = new Triangle();

    for(auto it: Obj)
        it->triangle();

    delete Obj[0];
    return 0;
}
```

[The output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDXmx.png)

But when I change to `std::shared_ptr` things are different which I could not understand.
The `main()` was:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> obj[3];

    obj[0] = std::make_shared<Equilateral>();
    obj[1] = std::make_shared<Isosceles>();
    obj[2] = std::make_shared<Triangle>();

    for(auto it: obj)
        it->triangle();

    return 0;
}
```

[The Output Now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ8UR.png)

Can anybody help me figure it out, why this happens?
may thanks in advance.

Comment: With the raw pointer array you don't actually delete `obj[1]` and `obj[2]`. It only seems like you do because `obj[0]` needs to call each of it's base types' destructors.

Comment: when I used     delete[] Obj; they did not destroyed at all.

Comment: You cannot do `delete[] Obj;` because `Obj` wasn't dynamically allocated. Even if it was, deleting an array of pointers does not also delete each element those pointers point to. You need to `delete` each element one by one.

Comment: Why is that confusing to you? In first example, you manually delete a single object, and calling all destructors through chain of inheritance. In second case, `shared_ptr` calls destructors for all 3 elements.

Comment: yes now I got it. for each element of the array I am creating all the base classes of it. and the time of deletion they also needed to be deleted separately. I was mistaken that the output of shared_ptr is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use raw pointers you only destroy the first object:

```
delete Obj[0];
```

and make other 2 leak, while when you use `std::shared_ptr` all 3 objects cleaned properly. This is exact reason why using smart pointers is recommended practice.

Comment: Then is the output for smart pointer is correct? why they delete shape or other classes at each deletion?

Comment: @Kallan both outputs are correct in a sense that they do what is expected given the code.

Comment: Because destructors are called for chain of hierarchy from most derived object to the base.

Comment: yes now I got it. for each element of the array I am creating all the base classes of it. and the time of deletion they also needed to be deleted separately. I was mistaken that the output of shared_ptr is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your second snippet is correct and the output is exactly as expected.
Your first snippet has a bug: you just `delete obj[0];`. What about `obj[1]` and `obj[2]`? If you delete all members of the array, you'll see that the difference between the outputs of two code samples vanish.
The good thing about smart pointers is that they are supposed to be used in a "fire-and-forget" manor.

Finally, read that book of yours with greater caution: you need to master the order of construction and destruction before starting anything about OOP.